# How to summarise data based on calculations on dates

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have data that looks like this (note dates are in DD-MM-YYYY format):

```
ID  date      drug  score
A   28/08/2016  2   3
A   29/08/2016  1   4
A   30/08/2016  2   4
A   2/09/2016   2   4
A   3/09/2016   1   4
A   4/09/2016   2   4
B   8/08/2016   1   3
B   9/08/2016   2   4
B   10/08/2016  2   3
B   11/08/2016  1   3
C   30/11/2016  2   4
C   2/12/2016   1   5
C   3/12/2016   2   1
C   5/12/2016   1   4
C   6/12/2016   2   4
C   8/12/2016   1   2
C   9/12/2016   1   2
```

For 'drug': 1=drug taken, 2=no drug taken.

I need to summarise for each ID:

- 0day: the mean score for days when a drug was taken.
- -1day: the mean score for the days immediately prior to when the drug was taken.
- +1day: the mean score for the days immediately after the drug was taken.

If a drug was taken 2 days in a row (eg the last 2 rows of the example) then these scores should not be counted in the -1day or +1day calculations (i.e., each of the last two rows would contribute to the 0day score but would not contribute to the other metrics).

So for this example data, I would need an output table like this:

```
    -1day   0day      +1day
A   3.5     4         4
B   3       3         4
C           3.25      2.5
```

**Note that there is not a record for all dates and that the -1day and +1day calculations need to be based on the actual dates and not just the records in the dataset.**

I have no idea how to do this.

I also have two additional bonus questions:

- I will most likely also need to calculate -2day and +2day scores, so need to be able to adapt an answer to do that.
- How could I calculate a NoDrug score, which is the mean of all days that are not within 5 days of a drug taking day.

Here is code to generate a dataframe with this example data:

```
data<-data.frame(ID=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C"),
                 date=as.Date(c("28/08/2016","29/08/2016","30/08/2016","2/09/2016","3/09/2016","4/09/2016","8/08/2016","9/08/2016","10/08/2016","11/08/2016","30/11/2016","2/12/2016","3/12/2016","5/12/2016","6/12/2016","8/12/2016","9/12/2016"),format= "%d/%m/%Y"),
                 drug=c(2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1),
                 score=c(3,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,3,4,5,1,4,4,2,2))
```

Comment: Should the value for `-1day` for group C be `2.5`?

Comment: No @MikeH., there should be no entry for -1day for ID C as there are no records for days prior to drug taking days for that ID (except for the 8/12/16 which is excluded as it is also a drug taking day). The -1day and +1day calculations need to be based on the actual date, not just the previous or next entry in the dataframe.
Some dates do not have a record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dplyr to get this:

#### Create data

```r
df <- data.frame(
  ID=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C"),
  date=as.Date(c("28/08/2016","29/08/2016","30/08/2016","2/09/2016","3/09/2016","4/09/2016","8/08/2016","9/08/2016","10/08/2016","11/08/2016","30/11/2016","2/12/2016","3/12/2016","5/12/2016","6/12/2016","8/12/2016","9/12/2016"),format= "%d/%m/%Y"),
  drug=c(2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1),
  score=c(3,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,3,4,5,1,4,4,2,2)
)

df

#>    ID       date drug score
#> 1   A 2016-08-28    2     3
#> 2   A 2016-08-29    1     4
#> 3   A 2016-08-30    2     4
#> 4   A 2016-09-02    2     4
#> 5   A 2016-09-03    1     4
#> 6   A 2016-09-04    2     4
#> 7   B 2016-08-08    1     3
#> 8   B 2016-08-09    2     4
#> 9   B 2016-08-10    2     3
#> 10  B 2016-08-11    1     3
#> 11  C 2016-11-30    2     4
#> 12  C 2016-12-02    1     5
#> 13  C 2016-12-03    2     1
#> 14  C 2016-12-05    1     4
#> 15  C 2016-12-06    2     4
#> 16  C 2016-12-08    1     2
#> 17  C 2016-12-09    1     2
```

#### Fill in missing rows (days)

A nice way to solve these sorts of problems, making rows *implicitly* missing observations *explicitly* missing, is to use [`tidyr::complete`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  complete(date = seq(min(date), max(date), by = "day"))

df1

#> Source: local data frame [22 x 4]
#> Groups: ID [3]
#> 
#> # A tibble: 22 x 4
#>        ID       date  drug score
#>    <fctr>     <date> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1      A 2016-08-28     2     3
#>  2      A 2016-08-29     1     4
#>  3      A 2016-08-30     2     4
#>  4      A 2016-08-31    NA    NA
#>  5      A 2016-09-01    NA    NA
#>  6      A 2016-09-02     2     4
#>  7      A 2016-09-03     1     4
#>  8      A 2016-09-04     2     4
#>  9      B 2016-08-08     1     3
#> 10      B 2016-08-09     2     4
#> # ... with 12 more rows
```

#### Categorize days

```r
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(day_of = drug == 1,
         day_before = (lead(drug) == 1 & day_of == FALSE),
         day_after = (lag(drug) == 1 & day_of == FALSE))

df2

#> Source: local data frame [22 x 7]
#> Groups: ID [3]
#> 
#> # A tibble: 22 x 7
#>        ID       date  drug score day_of day_before day_after
#>    <fctr>     <date> <dbl> <dbl>  <lgl>      <lgl>     <lgl>
#>  1      A 2016-08-28     2     3  FALSE       TRUE        NA
#>  2      A 2016-08-29     1     4   TRUE      FALSE     FALSE
#>  3      A 2016-08-30     2     4  FALSE         NA      TRUE
#>  4      A 2016-08-31    NA    NA     NA         NA     FALSE
#>  5      A 2016-09-01    NA    NA     NA      FALSE        NA
#>  6      A 2016-09-02     2     4  FALSE       TRUE        NA
#>  7      A 2016-09-03     1     4   TRUE      FALSE     FALSE
#>  8      A 2016-09-04     2     4  FALSE         NA      TRUE
#>  9      B 2016-08-08     1     3   TRUE      FALSE     FALSE
#> 10      B 2016-08-09     2     4  FALSE      FALSE      TRUE
#> # ... with 12 more rows
```

#### Summarise by day types

`dplyr::mutate_at` applies a function (in `funs()`) to all the columns selected in `vars()`. `summarise_at` operates the same way in terms of operating on a some selected columns, but instead of changing the values of the full dataset it reduces it done to one row per group. Can can read more about m[`mutate`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html), [`summarise`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html), and the special [`*_at`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) versions.

```r
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("day_")), funs(if_else(. == TRUE, score, NA_real_))) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("day_")), mean, na.rm = TRUE)

df3

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>       ID day_of day_before day_after
#>   <fctr>  <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1      A   4.00        3.5       4.0
#> 2      B   3.00        3.0       4.0
#> 3      C   3.25        NaN       2.5
```

Comment: Thanks @austensen - I think this is almost it, but importantly there is not a record for every date. So I think the LAG and LEAD functions will have to refer to date somehow.
As an example: row 13 of df1 in your example is incorrect. This record should have FALSE for 'day_before' as there is no record for 2016-12-04.

Comment: @mob Oh that makes sense, I was wondering why my answer for `-1 days` was different than yours. I think this solves that problem.

Comment: wow - thanks, this is great!
I can understand everything except for the last two lines. Can you explain what the mutate_at and summarise_at lines are doing?
Also, any thoughts on how I'd create a NoDrug score - i.e, mean score for all days that do not fall with 5 days of a drug taking day.

Comment: @mob I added a bit more description and links to documentation for the functions in the last two lines. I'm not sure about your other question right now but will try to come back to it later.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility using `dplyr` and its `lead` and `lag`functions:

```
  library(tidyverse)
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
    arrange(date)  %>% 
    mutate(
        # use ifelse for cases of drugs being take twice or more in a row
        `-1 day` = ifelse(dplyr::lag(drug) != 1, dplyr::lag(score, 1), NA),
        `+1 day` = ifelse(dplyr::lead(drug) != 1, dplyr::lead(score, 1), NA)
    ) %>%
    filter(drug == 1) %>% 
    summarise_all(mean, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
    select(
        `-1 day`,
        `0 day` = score,
        `+1 day`,
        -date,
        -drug
    )

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  `-1 day` `0 day` `+1 day`
     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1      3.5    4.00      4.0
2      3.0    3.00      4.0
3      3.0    3.25      2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use time series packages (like `zoo`) for such tasks.

```
library(zoo)
#function that handles conversion to zoo time series
my_zoo=function(x,idx) {
  date_range=seq(min(idx),max(idx),by="day")
  #add missing dates
  dummy_zoo=merge(zoo(x,idx),zoo(NA,date_range),all=TRUE)[,1]
  #add NA entry at top/bottom
  rbind(dummy_zoo,rbind(zoo(NA,max(idx)+1),zoo(NA,min(idx)-1)))
}

#split by ID, handle cases where drug is NA
split_data=lapply(split(data,df$ID),function(x) {
  list(score=my_zoo(x$score,x$date),
       taken=(my_zoo(x$drug,x$date)==1)&
         !is.na(my_zoo(x$drug,x$date)))})

#calculate stats
#your requirement that subsequent days with drug taken...
#... are completely omitted is a bit tricky to handle 
res=data.frame(
  mean_m1=sapply(split_data,function(x) {
    mean(x$score[diff(x$taken,-1)>0&
                   lag(diff(x$taken),+1)],
         na.rm=TRUE)}),
  mean_0=sapply(split_data,function(x) {
    mean(x$score[x$taken],
         na.rm=TRUE)}),
  mean_p1=sapply(split_data,function(x) {
    mean(x$score[diff(x$taken,+1)<0&
                   lag(diff(x$taken),-1)],
         na.rm=TRUE)}))
res
#   mean_m1 mean_0 mean_p1
# A     3.5   4.00     4.0
# B     3.0   3.00     4.0
# C     NaN   3.25     2.5
```